# How do I implementing Dice loss in a Tensorflow segmentation model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am new to TensorFlow, and I am trying to implement dice loss to my Image Segmentation model. The problem is, that all the tutorials I am getting are only showing what the function looks like. ie.

```
def dice_loss(inputs, target):
    num = target.size(0)
    inputs = inputs.reshape(num, -1)
    target = target.reshape(num, -1)
    smooth = 1.0
    intersection = (inputs * target)
    dice = (2. * intersection.sum(1) + smooth) / (inputs.sum(1) + target.sum(1) + smooth)
    dice = 1 - dice.sum() / num
    return dice
```

But none of them is showing me how it can actually be called in the model. i.e:

```
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
myTransformer = unet_model(output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES)
myTransformer.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                          metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

I have tried the code below but obviously, I don't have the variable `target` in my code:

```
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
myTransformer = unet_model(output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES)
myTransformer.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = dice_loss(inputs, outputs),
                                          metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

My question is, how do I call it and which parameters do I pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a class like this

```
class DiceLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
    inputs = y_pred
    target = y_true
    inputs = inputs.reshape(num, -1)
    target = target.reshape(num, -1)
    smooth = 1.0
    intersection = (inputs * target)
    dice = (2. * intersection.sum(1) + smooth) / (inputs.sum(1) + 
                 target.sum(1) + smooth)
    dice = 1 - dice.sum() / num
    return dice
```

and then calling it like this when compiling

```
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 2
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
myTransformer = unet_model(output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES)
myTransformer.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = DiceLoss(),
                                          metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```